# Trees with odd degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Define $t(n)$ to be the number of (unlabeled, unrooted) trees on n vertices such 
that each vertex has odd degree.  For example, $t(2) = t(4) = 1$. Every finite
nontrivial tree has endpoints and therefore at least has some vertices of odd
degree.  However, the global parity restriction considerably cuts down on the
range of possibilities.  For example, out of $23$ trees on $8$ vertices, only  $t(8)=3$
satisfy the requirements.

**Questions**: (1) Is it possible to generate a table of values for $t(n)$?

(2) Is anything known or conjectured about the growth rate of $t(n)$?

Remarks: (a) Note that $t(2n+1)=0$ since the sum of degrees must be even.

(b) All the trees counted by $t(n)$ are, in particular, series reduced
              (i.e. no vertices of degree two).

(c) The labeled cousins of the $t(n)$ appear as sequence $A007106$ in OEIS.

Comment: I am not sure that this has been done, but the standard approach to counting isomorphism classes of trees is quite flexible and will very likely work in this case. The obvious starting point is Harary and Palmer "Graphical Enumeration".

Comment: Tabulated at https://oeis.org/A250308 (which refers back here).

Answer (score 6):

First  compute the  OGF $T_1(z)$  for rooted  unlabeled tree  with all
vertices  of odd  degree except  for the  root. This  has  the combinatorial class equation
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{Z} + \mathcal{Z}\times
(\textsc{MSET}_{=2}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\textsc{MSET}_{=4}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\textsc{MSET}_{=6}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\cdots)$$
which is
$$\mathcal{T}_1 = \mathcal{Z}\times
(\textsc{MSET}_{=0}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\textsc{MSET}_{=2}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\textsc{MSET}_{=4}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\textsc{MSET}_{=6}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+\cdots)$$

Now the OGF of the cycle index of the symmetric group $S_n$ is
$$\exp
\left(a_1 w + a_2 \frac{w^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{w^3}{3} 
+ \cdots\right).$$

It follows that the operator $\textsc{MSET}_{\mathrm{even}}$ applied to
$T_1(z)$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}\exp
\left( T_1(z) + \frac{T_1(z^2)}{2} + \frac{T_1(z^3)}{3}
+\cdots\right)
\\+ \frac{1}{2}\exp
\left( -T_1(z) + \frac{T_1(z^2)}{2} - \frac{T_1(z^3)}{3}
+\cdots\right)$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right)
+ \frac{1}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right).$$

This gives the functional equation
$$T_1(z) = 
\frac{z}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right)
+ \frac{z}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right).$$

To extract coefficients from this start by observing that if
$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} A_n z^n =
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(z^q)}{q}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} B_n z^n =
\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{T(z^q)}{q}$$
then
$$A_n = \sum_{q|n} \frac{T_{n/q}}{q}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B_n = \sum_{q|n} (-1)^q \frac{T_{n/q}}{q}.$$

The functional equation now becomes
$$T_1(z) = \frac{z}{2} \exp A_1(z) + \frac{z}{2} \exp B_1(z)$$
and coefficient extraction produces
$$[z^n] T_1(z) = 
\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n-1}
\frac{1}{l(\lambda)!} {l(\lambda) \choose f}
\prod_{\lambda_i\in\lambda} A_{1,\lambda_i}
+\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n-1}
\frac{1}{l(\lambda)!} {l(\lambda) \choose f}
\prod_{\lambda_i\in\lambda} B_{1,\lambda_i}$$
where the $f_i$ are the multiplicities of the partition
i.e. $\lambda = 1^{f_1} 2^{f_2} 3^{f_3}\cdots$

This recurrence  gives a serviceable  but not excellent  recurrence to
compute $T_{1,n}.$

Now observe that the species $\mathcal{T}_2$ of rooted unlabeled trees
with odd vertex degree throughout is given by
$$\mathcal{T}_2 = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{MSET}_{\mathrm{odd}} (\mathcal{T}_1).$$

This gives the functional equation
$$T_2(z) = 
\frac{z}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right)
- \frac{z}{2}\exp
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{T_1(z^q)}{q}\right).$$

Proceeding as before we extract coefficients to obtain
$$[z^n] T_2(z) = 
\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n-1}
\frac{1}{l(\lambda)!} {l(\lambda) \choose f}
\prod_{\lambda_i\in\lambda} A_{1,\lambda_i}
-\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{\lambda\vdash n-1}
\frac{1}{l(\lambda)!} {l(\lambda) \choose f}
\prod_{\lambda_i\in\lambda} B_{1,\lambda_i}$$

Finally  use the  dissimilarity  characteristic theorem  for trees  as
presented  by  Harary and  Palmer  (section  3.2)  to obtain  for  the
generating function $T(z)$ of unrooted unlabeled trees with odd vertex
degree the relation

$$T(z) = T_2(z) - \frac{1}{2}(T_1(z)^2-T_1(z^2)).$$

Since $T_1(z)$ only has non-zero coefficients $T_{1,n}$ at odd values
of $n$ we obtain
$$[z^{2n}] T(z)
= T_{2,2n}
- \frac{1}{2} 
\left(\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} T_{1,2q+1} T_{1, 2n-2q-1} -T_{1,n}\right).$$

This gives the sequence (even indices)

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 13, 32, 74, 192, 497, 1379, 3844, 
\\ 11111, 32500, 96977, 292600, 894353,\ldots$$

The  first  two  generating   functions  were  verified  with  Maple's
**combstruct** package as follows.

```
with(combstruct);
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

evens :=
proc(struct)
local rval;

    if type(struct, function) then
        if op(0, struct) = Prod then
            return evens(op(2, struct))
        else
            rval := add(evens(op(q, struct)),
                        q=1..nops(struct));

            if type(nops(struct), even) then
                return 1+rval;
            fi;

            return rval;
        fi;
    fi;

    return 1;
end;


T1or2 :=
proc(n, what)
    option remember;
    local Apart, Bpart, A, B, p, cf;

    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    A := n -> add(T1(n/q)/q, q in divisors(n));
    B := n -> add((-1)^q*T1(n/q)/q, q in divisors(n));

    Apart := 0;
    Bpart := 0;

    p := firstpart(n-1);
    while type(p, `list`) do
        cf := 1/
        mul(q!, q in map(ent->ent[2],
                         convert(p, `multiset`)));

        Apart := Apart + cf*mul(A(q), q in p);
        Bpart := Bpart + cf*mul(B(q), q in p);

        p := nextpart(p);
    od;

    if what = T1 then
        return (Apart+Bpart)/2;
    else
        return (Apart-Bpart)/2;
    fi;
end;


T1_basic :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, gf;

    trees := { T1= Union(Z, Prod(Z, Set(T1, card >=1 ))),
               Z=Atom };

    gf := add(u^evens(t),
              t in allstructs([T1, trees, unlabeled], size=n));
    coeff(gf, u, n);
end;


T1 :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    T1or2(n, T1);
end;

T2_basic :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, gf, t, st;

    trees := { T1= Union(Z, Prod(Z, Set(T1, card >=1 ))),
               T2= Prod(Z, Set(T1, card >= 1)),
               Z=Atom };

    gf := 0;
    for t in allstructs([T2, trees, unlabeled], size=n) do
        st := op(2, t);
        if type(nops(st), odd) then
            gf := gf + u^evens(st);
        fi;
    od;

    coeff(gf, u, n-1);
end;

T2 :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    if n=1 then return 0 fi;

    T1or2(n, T2);
end;

T :=
proc(m)
    local n;

    if type(m, odd) then return 0 fi;

    n := m/2;

    T2(2*n)
    -1/2*(add(T1(2*q+1)*T1(2*n-2*q-1), q=0..n-1)- T1(n));
end;
```

The  last sequence  required more  work to  verify. I  used  the NAUTY
package  to generate  the trees  and a  Perl script  to check  for odd
degrees as shown below. This  confirmed the values from the recurrence
for $n$ up to $20.$ No claims are made regarding proficiency in Perl.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub decode_graph {
    my ($str) = @_;

    sub R {
        my (@args) = map {
            sprintf "%06b", $_;
        } @_;
        join '', @args;
    }

    my (@ents) = map {
        ord($_) - 63 
    } split //, $str;

    my $n = shift @ents;
    my @adj_data = split //, R(@ents);

    my $adj = []; my $pos = 0;
    for(my $ind2 = 1; $ind2 < $n; $ind2++){
        for(my $ind1 = 0; $ind1 < $ind2; $ind1++){
            $adj->[$ind1]->[$ind2] = $adj_data[$pos];
            $adj->[$ind2]->[$ind1] = $adj_data[$pos];

            $pos++;
        }
    }

    return $adj;
}

MAIN: {
    my $mx = shift || 2;
    die "out of range for GENG: $mx" 
        if $mx < 2 || $mx > 32;

    for(my $n=2; $n <= $mx; $n+=2){
        my $cmd = sprintf "./geng -c %d %d",
        $n, $n-1;

        my $count = 0;

        open GENG, "$cmd 2>/dev/null|";
        while(my $tree = <GENG>){
            chomp $tree; my $adj = decode_graph $tree;

            my $v;
            for($v = 0; $v < $n; $v++){
                my $deg = 0;
                for(my $w = 0; $w < $n; $w++){
                    my $ent = $adj->[$v]->[$w];
                    $deg++ if defined($ent) && $ent == 1;
                }

                last if $deg % 2 == 0;
            }

            $count++ if $v == $n;
        }
        close GENG;

        print "$count\n";
    }
}
```

This material is inspired by Harary and Palmer,
*Graphical Enumeration.*

**Addendum.**  For the sake  of completeness  we treat  the labeled
case as well (labeled unrooted trees with odd vertex degree).

The combinatorial  class $\mathcal{T}_1$ of labeled  rooted trees with
odd vertex degree except at the root has the specification

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{T}_1 =
\mathcal{Z}+\mathcal{Z} \times
\left(\textsc{SET}_{=2}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \textsc{SET}_{=4}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \textsc{SET}_{=6}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \cdots\right).$$
This is
$$\mathcal{T}_1 =
\mathcal{Z} \times
\left(\textsc{SET}_{=0}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \textsc{SET}_{=2}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \textsc{SET}_{=4}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \textsc{SET}_{=6}(\mathcal{T}_1)
+ \cdots\right).$$

This gives the functional equation
$$T_1(z) = z \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{T_1(z)^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
or
$$T_1(z) = 
\frac{z}{2} \exp(T_1(z)) + \frac{z}{2} \exp(-T_1(z)).$$

We can extract coefficients from this using the residue operator.
We have
$$[z^n] T_1(z) = \frac{1}{n} [z^{n-1}] T_1'(z) =
\frac{1}{n} \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n}} T_1'(z).$$

Put $T_1(z) = w$ so that
$$z = \frac{2w}{\exp(w)+\exp(-w)}.$$

This gives for the residue
$$\frac{1}{n} \; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{(\exp(w)+\exp(-w))^{n}}{(2w)^{n}}.$$

Now we have
$$(\exp(w)+\exp(-w))^{n}
= \exp(nw)\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \exp(-2wq).$$

This gives for the residue the value
$$\frac{1}{n\times 2^n} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^p}{p!}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \frac{(-2q)^{n-1-p}}{(n-1-p)!}.$$

Multiplying by $n!$ because we have an EGF yields

$$T_{1, n} = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose p} n^p
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-2q)^{n-1-p}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-2q)^{n-1}
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose p} n^p (-2q)^{-p}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-2q)^{n-1}
\left(1-\frac{n}{2q}\right)^{n-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{2^n} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (n-2q)^{n-1}.$$

This gives at odd indices the sequence

$$1, 3, 65, 3787, 427905, 79549811, 22036379521, 8513206310715,
\\ 4374455745966593, 2885264091484122979, 2376040584184726335681,
\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A036778](https://oeis.org/A036778) where we find
confirmation of these computations.

Continuing we find that  the combinatorial class $\mathcal{T}_2$ of
rooted labeled trees with odd vertex degree including at the root is
given by

$$\mathcal{T}_2 = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}_{\mathrm{odd}}(\mathcal{T}_1)$$
and has the functional equation
$$T_2(z) = z \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{T_1(z)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
= \frac{z}{2} \exp (T_1(z)) - \frac{z}{2} \exp (-T_1(z)).$$

We have

$$T_2'(z) = \frac{1}{z} T_2(z) + T_1(z) T_1'(z).$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$\frac{T_{2,n}}{(n-1)!} =
\frac{T_{2,n}}{n!} + [z^{n-1}] T_1(z) T_1'(z)$$

which yields with the remaining coefficient extractor

$$T_{2,n} = \frac{n!}{n-1} \; \underset{z}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{z^{n}} T_1(z) T_1'(z).$$

We get from the latter

$$\; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{(\exp(w)+\exp(-w))^{n}}{(2w)^{n}} w
= \frac{1}{2^n} \; \underset{w}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{(\exp(w)+\exp(-w))^{n}}{w^{n-1}}.$$

Similar to before we obtain

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1) \times 2^n} \sum_{p=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^p}{p!}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \frac{(-2q)^{n-2-p}}{(n-2-p)!}
\\ = \frac{n}{2^n} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (n-2q)^{n-2}.$$

The even indices of this give the sequence
$$2, 16, 576, 47104, 6860800, 1562148864, 512260833280, \\
228646878969856, 133296779352342528, 98349146136012390400,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A060279](https://oeis.org/A060279)
where the calculation is confirmed.

As  we are  working  in the  labeled  universe the  count of  unrooted
labeled trees with odd vertex degree throughout is given by
$$\frac{T_{2,n}}{n}$$
which gives the sequence (even indices)
$$1, 4, 96, 5888, 686080, 130179072, 36590059520, 14290429935616, 
\\ 7405376630685696, 4917457306800619520,\ldots$$

which is indeed [OEIS A007106](https://oeis.org/A007106) as observed by the OP.

Comment: impressive - many thanks