# Number of labeled trees with a certain condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was wondering about that one:

> A "varied Tree" T is a tree where for each 2 distinct vertices (non-leaves) u,v $ deg(u) \neq deg(v)$. How many varied trees are there for the set of vertices $\{1,2,3...11\} $

Well, I thought about using Prufer code, but I am confused with all the possible cases there are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we seek  to enumerate "labeled varied trees"  i.e. trees where
the  degrees of non-leaves  in the  tree are  unique.  We  use Pruefer
codes. The degree of a node  in the tree corresponding to a given code
is one more than the number of times it appears in the code. Leaves do
not appear.   The problem thus  reduces to counting the  Pruefer codes
where  the number  of times  a value  between $1$  and $n$  appears is
unique.

This calculation is  very similar to the material  at the following
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827737/).

Recall the species of set partitions
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

which immediately gives the generating function

$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

Now in the present case we  seek to limit the number of appearances of
a set to zero or one. Therefore we introduce

$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

Starting  with $v_1$ and  extracting the  coefficients on  $v_1^0$ and
$v_1^1$ we get

$$\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 2} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
+ \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 2} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right) u \frac{z}{1}
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 2} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z}{1}\right).$$

The same procedure for $v_2^0$ and $v_2^1$ yields

$$\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 3} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z}{1}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z^2}{2}\right).$$

We get for $v_3^0$ and $v_3^1$

$$\exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 4} u v_q \frac{z^q}{q!}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z}{1}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z^2}{2}\right)
\left(1+u\frac{z^3}{6}\right).$$

The pattern  should be clear.   The conclusion is that  the generating
function for set partitions with  unique sizes and sizes at most $n-2$
is

$$H(z, u) = \prod_{q=1}^{n-2} \left(1+u\frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

Let me point out that this  can be derived by inspection without going
through the species  of set partitions. Each term in  the product is a
chooser type  gadget that  we must pass  through and which  enforces a
choice of either taking a set of size $q$ or not taking it.

The desired count is then given by

$$(n-2)! \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} {n\choose k} \times k! 
\times [u^k] [z^{n-2}] H(z, u).$$

This will produce the following sequence, which starts at $n=1:$

$$1, 1, 3, 4, 65, 126, 637, 21344, 57465, 330850, 2023901,
\\ 156312432, 502733101, 3464645380, 21505493115, 194182086016,
\ldots $$

The answer for eleven vertices is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]
{\Large 2023901.}$$

The Maple code for this including enumeration was as follows.

```
with(combinat);

trees_varied :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local ind, d, a, mset, deg, res;

    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    res := 0;

    for ind from n^(n-2) to 2*n^(n-2)-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, n);
        a := [seq(d[q]+1, q=1..n-2)];

        mset := convert(a, `multiset`);
        deg := map(ent -> ent[2]+1, mset);

        if nops(deg) = nops(convert(deg, `set`))
        then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;
    od;

    res;
end;


X :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local H;

    if n=1 or n=2 then return 1 fi;

    H :=
    coeff(expand((n-2)!*mul(1+u*z^q/q!, q=1..n-2)), z, n-2);

    add(binomial(n,k)*k!*coeff(H, u, k), k=1..n-2);
end;
```